# Noun phrase + prepositional phrase + relative clause - Which noun is modified by the relative clause?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"The type of an object determines the set of values (that) it can have."

In the above sentence, which noun is modified by the relative clause "(that) it can have"?

a.) The noun "set" of the noun phrase "the set"

b.) The noun "values" of the prepositional phrase "of values"

Comment: It's almost redundant to use 'the set of values it can have'; 'the values it can have' has the same meaning. I acknowledge that the phrase is idiomatic and has the pragmatic effect of underlining that you're talking about _all_ the possible values. But I'd not consider 'that it can have' to be modifying 'set' any more than 'all' in 'all the possible values that it can have'.

Comment: In constructions like this, the relative clause is normally seen as modifying the noun that is complement of the preposition "of". On that basis, the relative clause is modifying "values" not "set".

Comment: BillJ Thank you very much for your simple and clear answer.

Comment: Encouraged by your name, I'll give an answer based on mathematics rather than on English semantics.The phrase "that it can have" modifies "values", because values, not sets, are the sort of thing an object can have. Even if one says that an object can have such-and-such set of values, it means that the object can have each of the values in the set.

Comment: @Andreas But is "that" a relative pronoun or a conjunction (introducing a noun clause) in the sentence ? What if the sentence were, "The type of an object determines the set of values that provides a solution." There "that" is clearly a relative pronoun. In that sentence would it modify "set" or "values"?

Comment: @Zan700 Your modified sentence would, despite the mathematics of the situation, have the relative clause modifying the singular noun "set" rather than the plural "values" because it uses the singular "provides". To make it mathematically correct it should read "... the set of values that provide solutions."

Comment: @Andreas So if it were a simpler construction, let's say, "He likes the kind of cars that (go or goes) fast," the relative pronoun would modify the noun the verb agrees with?

Answer (score 1):

It can have values.
It can have a set of values.
I think the relative clause can be said to modify the noun "values" or the whole noun phrase "set of values"

Comment: "Set of values" is a noun phrase.